# Conditionally Show Grid View Columns Based On Checkboxlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a requirement where I have two gridviews.  One for the header, and one for the actual data.  I want the header grid to start at index[0] regardless of any situation, but I want the data grid to start show/hide based at index[1] (meaning the first two rows of the grid will be displayed regardless of check box choice.

I tried this syntax, but this is basing both grids off of the index[1] - how can I conditionally show for each seperate grid?

```
    protected void ShowClickedOnly_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridviewData.Visible = true;
    gridViewHeader.Visible = true;

    var columnname = string.Empty;
    foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem item in checkboxlistPeople.Items)
    {
        columnname = item.Text;
        var index = GetColumnIndex(gridViewHeader, columnname);
        string number = index.ToString();
        if (index > 1)
        {
            gridViewHeader.Columns[index].Visible = item.Selected;
            gridviewData.Columns[index].Visible = item.Selected;
        }
    }
}
protected void checkboxlistPeople_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var items = checkboxlistPeople.Items;
}

private int GetColumnIndex(GridView grid, string ColName)
{
    foreach (DataControlField col in grid.Columns)
    {
        if (col.HeaderText.ToLower().Trim() == ColName.ToLower().Trim())
        {
            return grid.Columns.IndexOf(col);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**EDIT**
To combat this I attempted to get crafty and use the below - however this now returns a "ghost" empty column at the end of the grid, so 4 rows return instead of 3.

```
if (index > 0)
{
    gridViewHeader.Columns[index].Visible = item.Selected;
    gridviewData.Columns[index].Visible = item.Selected;
    if (index > 1)
    {
        gridViewHeader.Columns[index].Visible = item.Selected;
        gridviewData.Columns[index].Visible = item.Selected;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
This is the HTML markup for the page

```
    <div runat="server" id="checkboxlistPeople">    
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbxSelected" runat="server" RepeatLayout="table" RepeatColumns="1" RepeatDirection="vertical" OnSelectedIndexChanged="informationSelected_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:CheckBoxList>    
</div>
<div id="btnForData"><asp:Button ID="btnDisplayData" runat="server" onclick="btnDisplay_Click" Text="Display Information" /> </div>   

<div id="gridviewData" >
    <asp:GridView ID="gridviewHeader" runat="server" CssClass="Grid" AutoGenerateColumns="false"> 
        <Columns>                    
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Header" HeaderText="Header"  HeaderStyle-Width="50%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DataElement1" HeaderText="DataElement1" HeaderStyle-Width="8%"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DataElement2" HeaderText="DataElement2" HeaderStyle-Width="8%"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DataElement3" HeaderText="DataElement4" HeaderStyle-Width="8%"></asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
<asp:GridView ID="gridviewData" runat="server" CssClass="Grid" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="False"> 
    <Columns>
        <asp:templatefield HeaderText="Display"><itemtemplate><asp:checkbox ID="cbSelect" Checked="true" CssClass="gridCB" runat="server"></asp:checkbox></itemtemplate></asp:templatefield>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Header" HeaderText="Header"  HeaderStyle-Width="50%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DataElement1" HeaderText="DataElement1"  HeaderStyle-Width="50%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"> </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DataElement2" HeaderText="DataElement2" HeaderStyle-Width="8%"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DataElement3" HeaderText="DataElement3" HeaderStyle-Width="8%"></asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: show the GridView Html code.

Comment: @AsifAli72090 - please see edit.  Have added the requested information